# Update Database Using AJAX in Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-models, django-views

So I have an AJAX command, which passes information to a views.py method (I have verified that the passing works from the HTML->urls.py->views.py, so that's all good), but once I have it in "views.py", I have no idea how to get it to update in the database itself.

I have tried to avoid using a forms.py file if possible, but if that is the only option I'll bend to it.

The AJAX function is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/perform/acts/update/{{  act.id  }}/',
    type : "POST",
    data : {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : "{{  csrf_token  }}",
        furtherData : furtherData
    },
    success : function(result) {}
});
```

The views.py function is...so far, lacking, to say the least, but this is where I'm sort of lost:

```
def update_act(request, furtherData_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
      ?
      return HttpResponse(?)
```

A big reason for doing this this way was performing updates without reloading and without having to add another module. I have been using Django for only a couple weeks, so it could be something easy that I'm missing...

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view function:

```
def my_view_action(request, any_pk_id):
    from django.http import JsonResponse
    if request.method=='POST' and request.is_ajax():
        try:
            obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=any_pk_id)
            obj.data_attr = request.POST['attr_name']
            obj.save()
            return JsonResponse({'status':'Success', 'msg': 'save successfully'})
         except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'status':'Fail', 'msg': 'Object does not exist'})
     else:
         return JsonResponse({'status':'Fail', 'msg':'Not a valid request'}
```

> **This function directly save data on your DB, For validate it first use form then proceed to save action.**
>
> > ---Steps---
> >     - Create a form for model.
> >     - Fill data on this model via request/object.
> >     - Run validate on form then save to db via form or via model.

For more info
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: To access form data in the views just do `request.POST`

Answer (score 4):

```
def update_act(request,furtherData_id):
    from django.http import JsonResponse
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        obj=MyObj.objects.get(pk=furtherData_id)
        obj.data=request.POST['furtherData']
        obj.save()
        return JsonResponse({'result':'ok'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'result':'nok'}
```

Comment: I feel like this is the "right answer" based on the parameters the OP provided, but this does blindly save the input to the DB. Using a ModelForm and supplying `obj` as an instance to that form would provide some data validation here.